# Is it possible to load a different version of SQLite in a PHP script?

Tags: php, sqlite

My webhoster is running a very old version of SQLite and since I am on a shared server, I can't update it and they will not update it for just me.

Is it possible via a PHP script to load a different version just for my script?

I Tried to run the PHP script with the default SQLite version and it doesn't work.

Comment: You should add the version numbers to your question, that is from SQLite and also the PHP version.

Comment: Using PHP, you can find out what the host uses for their OS and kernel. You can spin up a docker container with that OS and kernel and compile SQLite. You could copy the files over to the host then. Ref: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028047592-Installing-a-custom-version-of-SQLite3. You can also try copying precompiled binaries to the web host, perhaps. Ref: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: no sane shared hoster will allow you to sideload any binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your hoster is an amateur the answer to your "can I side load alien binaries" is most likely "no", for many reasons, incl. security and server stability. Contact them and ask if they can upgrade it for you and if they won't - migrate elsewhere or start using i.e. VPS (if you can administer it).